# Trying to Build a Python Package in Github Actions, Version Number Doesn't Come Up

Tags: github-actions

I have written the following yml script to build a project for Python in github actions. The Version number comes from `setup.py` which has this variable:

```
VERSION: '0.0.9'
```

```
name: Build cs package

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  VERSION: $(python setup.py --version)

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Run tests
        run: python -m unittest discover -v

      - name: Build artifact
        run:  |
          echo $VERSION
          python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: cs-$VERSION
          path: dist
```

However, at the end I get the package named as `cs-$VERSION` instead of `cs-0.0.9`. How do I get the variable printed instead of $VERSION?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this replace `name: cs-$VERSION` with `name: cs-${{ env.VERSION }}` This allows the value "VERSION" obtained from "setup.py" to be used in the artifact name. The double curly braces around "env.VERSION" indicate that it is a variable that should be evaluated and replaced with its value during runtime.

Comment: thanks for this, but now I get `cs-$(python setup.py --version)` instead of `cs-0.0.9`